# regex inside tags with specified string

Tags: php, regex

I'm not very good at regex but i have a string like this :

```
 $str = '<span id="MainStatuSSpan" style="background: brown;"> Incoming: 012345678  Group- SUPERMONEY &nbsp;   Fronter:  - 992236  UID: Y3281602190002004448</span>';
 $pattern = '/(?:Fronter:  - )[0-9]{1,6}/i';    
 preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
 /*** ^^^^^^^ This prints :*/
 Array ( [0] => Fronter: - 992236 )
```

In case of the `Fronter` is not with `-` or spaces I don't get the `Fronter - number`.

Can anyone help with an example that works in any case, there is always a `Fronter` and a `number`.

Comment: you can use `(?:Fronter:\W*)[0-9]{1,6}`

Comment: Maybe `Fronter:[^\d]+\d+`

Comment: Thank you, in both cases it works

Comment: @AbraCadaver it will fail against `Fronter:992236` so better would be `[^\d]*`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh: yes good thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`Fronter:\W*[0-9]{1,6}`](https://regex101.com/r/Byu5Nk/1)

`Fronter:\W*[0-9]{1,6}` : match `Fronter:`

- `\W*` : zero or more non-word characters
- `[0-9]{1,6}` one to six digits

you regex will also find a match with `Fronter:99222236` so you must use `\b` to avoid overflow digit length

[`Fronter:[- ]*[0-9]{1,6}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/lGbKTe/1)